# C (or asm): how to execute c code stored in memory (copied from labels)

Tags: c, memory, assembly

I try to "inline" my VM by copying code segments from C code between labels to memory allocated by malloc. So I have Ops defined with start and end labels, and I want to copy the instruction defined by the following code to a buffer and then get executed (Im not sure if this is even possible)

```
OP_PUSH0_START:
    sp += 4; *sp = 0; // I WANT THE INSTRUCTIONS OF THIS LINE COPIED TO THE BUFFER
OP_PUSH0_END:
```

to do so I thought the following code snippet will work

```
void * ptr0 = &&OP_PUSH0_START;
void * ptr1 = &&OP_PUSH0_END;
while(ptr0 < ptr1)
{
    buf[c++] = *ptr0;
    ptr0++;
}
goto buf; //jump to start of buffer
```

but I cant eaven read it out without getting a memory error

I would be happy about any links or any suggestions how to achieve this

Comment: Data allocated on the stack or heap is generally not executable. You might be able to use operating system primitives to make a memory area executable.

Comment: you'd do way better using something built for this kind of thing, like dynasm, especially as what you are doing is *very* brittle...

Comment: also when you do a jump, you will need to jump back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only legal way to transfer execution to an arbitrary location is to use a function pointer. `goto` only jumps to labels, not arrays or anything else.

Also you cannot take the address of a label. A label is not an object or a function.

It is rightly pointed out that data areas are often placed in memory whose content cannot be executed as CPU instructions. There are, however, often workarounds for that. Windows and Linux provide functions to change the permissions/rights/privileges/whatever-you-call-it of a region of the memory.

For example, here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7859813/968261) of doing the kind of thing you're trying to do on Windows.

Comment: in GCC C you can take the address of a label with &&, I think they call it "first order label", but its not part of ANSI C, and PUSH0_START returned .....206 for me and PUSH0_END is .....217 (11 bytes for some assignment sounds plausible to me, but im an assembler noob), and actually the source in the link you gave me worked!! so much thanks, the only thing that I need to know now is how to read out the code between the labels and insert it to the buffer....

Comment: If you have an address of accessible memory, read from it. Use pointers. It should be `char*` kind of pointers, not `void*`.

Comment: yea the problem is somehow that this code i read out will not execute correctly... is there something like a "single line assembler" (so i write "mov EAX, 4" and it gives me the bytecode equivalent?

Comment: There are some projects like that. Look up asmjit, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to Alexey's answer I would link my own sample of creating the jit-executor.

[How to make a C program that can run x86 hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252707/how-to-make-a-c-program-that-can-run-x86-hex-codes/11253633#11253633)

The [AsmJIT library](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) is a fine x86/x64 "one line" assembler which actually creates a complete executable chunk of memory.

The portable version of jit engine is the [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/). It supports the creation of function trampolines for the ARM/x86/PowerPC/MIPS architectures.

The thing about "pointer to the label" cannot be standard in C, because there are hardware architectures in which data and code do not share the same memory.