# How can I execute a function from its memory address in C / assembly?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, disassembly

I have the following assembly function (shown with objdump already)

```
0000000000000000 <add>:
   0:   b8 06 00 00 00          mov    $0x6,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

Now in C I made the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*funcp) (int x);

unsigned char foo[] = {0xb8,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xc3};

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  funcp f = (funcp)foo;
  i = (*f);
  
  printf("exit = %d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

In the global variable foo I typed the memory address of my function in assembly and tried to execute it but it does not return 6 as expected.
How can I execute functions for their memory addresses? furthermore, where can i research more on the subject?

obs: sometimes I got the Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Comment: For a start, you have to use `()` to call a function.

Comment: Why not simply call it by name?

Comment: `i = (*f)` -> `i = (*f)(0)`

Comment: Shouln't it be `typedef int (*funcp) ();`? Your function in  assembly takes no parameters.

Comment: True, this function does not receive any parameters, but even changing to () the value of variable i is still wrong.
I tried (0) and got segmetantion fault. Anyway I would like it to work for functions of n parameters

Comment: @SbasicDY what is your platform? On my platform (Windows) it almost works, but I cannot execute code that is actually data. On your platform yopu may have a similar issue.

Comment: The data section is usually not executable, meaning your code will run into a segmentation fault.

Comment: I am running through WSL 1 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

I compile and run with gcc as follows:

gcc -o out test.c

./out

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252707/how-to-make-a-c-program-that-can-run-x86-hex-codes/11253633#11253633) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447957/c-or-asm-how-to-execute-c-code-stored-in-memory-copied-from-labels) might be interesting to read

Comment: @fuz, I also tried to compile it as follows to avoid this:

gcc -Wa, - execstack -Wall -c temp1.c

Comment: @SbasicDY It's `gcc -Wa, -z execstack ...`

Comment: Using -z I get the followiing error: gcc -Wa,-z execstack -c temp1.c
gcc: error: execstack: No such file or directory

Comment: `gcc -z execstack temp1.c` works for me. I get `6` as output.

Comment: @SbasicDY That does not make the data segment executable, only the stack.

Comment: @fuz You are right and TBH I didn't expect it to work unless I'd make `foo` a local variable, but it works anyway.

Comment: if you make it a const it may pull it into .text and make that then in an executable space, but the real issue esp, if down the road you want to do self-modifying code, you have to solve the executable space problem and not just make this example work.

Comment: @fuz: `-z execstack` on Linux made *all* readable pages executable until very recent kernel versions.  Linux's ELF program loader set the read-implies-exec process "personality" flag when seeing the executable GNU stack metadata. [Linux default behavior against \`.data\` section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64833715) - `PT_GNU_STACK == RWX` no longer implies exec-all; I just updated my Arch Linux and `gcc -zexecstack` doesn't make .data (or `.rodata`) executable.  See also [Unexpected exec permission from mmap...](//stackoverflow.com/q/58260465).

Comment: @fuz: But since that change, there are now several outdated answers on the multiple duplicates of this question which suggest using `gcc -zexecstack`.  Unless there's a handy way to set the READ_IMPLIES_EXEC personality flag directly (including for new kernel where GNU-stack doesn't do it), only the `mprotect` or `mmap`+`memcpy` answers are now viable for testing shellcode-like arrays this way.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had hoped something like `-Wl,-N` would do the trick, but the manual does not indicate such.  Alternatively, perhaps it is possible via some `__attribute__` to place the variable in the text section?

Comment: @fuz: Yes, `__attribute__((section(".text")))` works.  I get *Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccNetmKQ.s:28: Warning: ignoring changed section attributes for .text* but it does run.   https://godbolt.org/z/draGeh.  On my desktop, `-Wl,-N` makes it fail to link: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s`.  *Both* of those things (array in text section, and read/write text section) would be necessary for a non-const executable array.

Answer (score 0):

The NX flag might be your 'friend' here. Parts of memory which are never meant to be executed as binary machine code can be marked as No-eXecute. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit . So, depending on architecture, operating system and settings, and even BIOS settings.

So this feature might be on or off. If NX is used on the data-section of your program, it will not run. You will need to mmap() a piece of memory with PROT_EXEC set, copy the data in, then run it.

For the following, I changed the binary to be an amd64 code (+1 func). When using the mmap() copy, it works. When directly calling foo, it fails (on my machine with NX active)

(code without err-check, freeing of mem, etc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef int (*funcp) (int x);

unsigned char foo[] = {0x8d,0x47,0x01,0xc3};
//unsigned char foo[] = {0xc3,0xb8,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xc3};

int main(void)
{
  int i;

  void *mem2;

  mem2 = mmap(0,4096,PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_EXECUTABLE,-1,0);

  memcpy(mem2,foo,sizeof(foo));


  funcp f = (funcp)mem2;
  i = f(42);

  printf("exit = %d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not fully safe in GNU C without `__builtin___clear_cache` to let the compiler know the store into that buffer isn't "dead", i.e. that it will be read as code.  (No actual cache invalidation has to happen on x86, with its coherent I-cache, but there is a possible compile-time optimization problem.)  See [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960721)